# What is a pointer to array, int (*ptr)[10], and how does it work?

Tags: c++, arrays, c, pointers, pointer-to-array

```cpp
int (*ptr)[10];
```

I was expecting `ptr` to be an array of pointers of `10` integers.

I'm not understanding how it is a pointer to an array of `10` integers.

Comment: It is a **pointer to an array of 10 elements.** Whereas this `int *ptr[10]` is the **array of 10 pointers**.

Comment: [The Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

Comment: C or C++ ? Please pick one

Comment: https://cdecl.org/

Comment: As you're new to the site, let me remind you that you can choose to accept one of these answers, more details in [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [meaning of these pointers, pointer-to-pointer, function pointer and array pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62265769/meaning-of-these-pointers-pointer-to-pointer-function-pointer-and-array-pointe)

Comment: No one really does all these figuring out things. You just get used to the common ones like array pointers, array references, function pointers etc, and when you find something particularly messy, you use tools like https://cdecl.org/.

Answer (score 5):

I like to read it like this: (great answers already posted)

```cpp
int (*ptr) [10];
     ^ a pointer
           ^ to an array of 10
^ ints
```

vs

```cpp
int* ptr[10];
        ^ array of 10
   ^ pointer to int
```

Comment: Yours is not so bad either :)

Answer (score 4):

`ptr` is of type "pointer to array of 10 int". In your declaration it is uninitialized so it doesn't point to any object. To make it point to an array:

```cpp
int arr[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

// initialize in the declaration:
int (*ptr) [10] = &arr;

// or after:
int (*ptr) [10];
ptr = &arr;
```

Comment: Not my downvote. The only inaccuracy I see is that the pointer is default initialized (with an indeterminate value), rather than being uninitialized.

Answer (score 3):

A pointer to an array of 10 `int`s is meant to point to arrays of 10 elements, no more, no less, or in case you have a 2D array, to point to a given row of such array, provided the it has exactly 10 columns.

An array of pointers to `int`, `int *ptr[10]`, is just that, it has 10 pointers to `int` and to each one you can assing an address of an `int`, it can be part of an array or not.

Example 1:

```
int (*ptr)[10];

int arr[10];
ptr = &arr; //correct, arr has 10 elements

int arr2[12]; 
ptr = &arr2; //not correct, arr2 does not have 10 elements
```

Such pointer can be used to point to a 2D array with undetermined number of rows but a fixed number of columns.

Example 2:

```c
int arr[5][10];
ptr = arr; //correct, pointer to the 1st row of a 2D array with 10 cols
ptr++; //now points to the second row        
    
int arr2[5][12]; 
ptr = arr2; //not correct, incompatible pointer, has too many cols
```

Example 3:

```c
int(*ptr)[3];

int arr[2][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 7}};
ptr = arr;

printf("%d", ptr[1][2]); //array indexing is identical as using arr[1][2]
```

---

**Array of pointer vs pointer to array**

An advantage of  pointer to array comes when it's time to dynamically allocate/free memory:

Example with a 2D array with 4 rows and 5 columns:

```
int (*ptr)[5]; 
ptr = calloc(5, sizeof *ptr); //simple assignment

free(ptr); //simple deallocation
```

```
int *ptr[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)  //each pointer needs it's own allocation
    ptr[i] = calloc(5, sizeof **ptr);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)  //each pointer needs to be freed
    free(ptr[i]);
```

On the other hand if you have an array of pointers you can have an *uneven* array, that is to say that the 1st row can have 10 `int`s but the 2nd can have 20:

```
int *ptr[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    ptr[i] = calloc( i + 1, sizeof **ptr);
```

In the above example the 1st row of the 2D array has space for 1 `int`, the second for 2, the third for 3 and so on.

Answer (score 2):

A declaration gives a “picture” of how a variable will be used.<sup>1</sup> `int (*ptr) [10]` says “When `(*ptr)[i]` is used in an expression, it is an `int`.” From this, we can derive the type of `ptr`:

- Since `(*ptr)[i]` is an `int`, `(*ptr)` must be an array of `int`.
- Since `(*ptr)` is an array of `int`, `*ptr` must be an array of `int`.
- Since `*ptr` is an array of `int`, `ptr` must be a pointer to an array of `int`.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> Kernighan and Ritchie, *The C Programming Language*, 1978, page 90.

Answer (score 1):

In both expressions and declarations, the postfix operators `[]` and `()` have higher precedence than unary `*`.  Because of this, the declarations

```
T *a[N]; // a is an array of pointer to T
T *f();  // f is a function returning pointer to T
```

are parsed as

```
T *(a[N]); // result of a[i] will be dereferenced
T *(f());  // result of f() will be dereferenced
```

If you want a pointer to an array or a pointer to a function, you must explicitly group the `*` operator with whatever the pointer expression will be:

```
T (*a)[N]; // result of *a will be subscripted
T (*f)();  // result of *f will be executed
```

The pointer does not have to be a simple identifier - you can have a function that returns a pointer to an array:

```
T (*f())[N]; // result of *f() will be subscripted
```

or an array of pointers to functions

```
T (*a[N])(); // result of *a[i] will be executed
```